# Can sendtoaddress use account other than ""?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, sendtoaddress

sendtoaddress is using the "" account by default. Is it possible to make it use any other account name?

Comment: You want `sendfrom`, but the whole account feature is deprecated so you should redesign your application to not use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Accounts are deprecated and `labels` are the alternative for `accounts`.

I'd recommend using latest Bitcoin [0.17.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.17.0) which has multi wallet features which can isolate each user, further read:

> https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Multi-wallet_RPC_calls
>
> https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13058

Answer (score 0):

`sendtoaddress` Doesn't support accounts at all

```
Parameter #1—to address
Parameter #2—amount to spend
Parameter #3—a comment
Parameter #4—a comment about who the payment was sent to
Result—a TXID of the sent transaction
```

What you can do as alternative is `getaccountaddress` to get bitcoin address of an account and then `sendtoaddress`

Comment: actually i want to pick the source account..not the destination. By default sendtoaddress picks the "" account as source. Is it possible to pick any other account?

Comment: Yes, put account name instead of "", like that "myaccount"

Answer (score -1):

First do `move` command to move bitcoins from custom account to "", for example

`bitcoin-cli move "account_with_bitcoins" "" amount_to_send`

And then use `sendtoaddress`

`bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "address" amount_to_send`